# React onLoad event on image tag is not getting called when using conditional render

Tags: reactjs, image, onload, react-hooks

I'm using the stateless functional component to add spinner while image is loading from the external resource, like so:

```
function ExternalImage(props) {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  function onLoad() {
    console.log('loaded');
    setLoaded(true);
  }
  return loaded
     ? <img 
        onLoad={onLoad}
        src={props.src}
        alt={props.alt}
        {...props} 
       /> 
     : <Spin />
}
```

And use it like so:

```
<ExternalImage src={image.src} alt={image.alt} className="image" />
```

Why would the `onLoad` never get called?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When image is not loaded you aren't actually rendering the image. You need to render it for its onLoad to fire

```
function ExternalImage(props) {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  function onLoad() {
    console.log('loaded');
    setLoaded(true);
  }
  return (
    <>
        <img 
        style={{display: loaded? 'block': 'none'}}
        onLoad={onLoad}
        src={props.src}
        alt={props.alt}
        {...props} 
       /> 
       {!loaded && <Spin /> }
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: this answer saved me! thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your condition in return statement prevent rendering image, so it will be never loaded.

```
function ExternalImage(props) {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  function onLoad() {
    console.log('loaded');
    setLoaded(true);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <img 
        onLoad={onLoad}
        src={props.src}
        alt={props.alt}
        {...props} 
      /> 
      {!loaded && <Spin />}
    </>
  )
}
```

Also, remember to use useCallback hook to memoize your onLoad function:

```
function ExternalImage(props) {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const onLoad = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('loaded');
    setLoaded(true);
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <img 
        onLoad={onLoad}
        src={props.src}
        alt={props.alt}
        {...props} 
      /> 
      {!loaded && <Spin />}
    </>
  )
}
```