# 'load' event listener for detect image is done loaded is not working in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to console some message when image is fully loaded using 'load' listener, but the code did not work, how to properly write a 'load' event listener in react ? Thankyou

```
  useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
   const imageTest = document.querySelector('img')
   const isLoaded = imageTest.complete && imageTest.naturalHeight !== 0
   console.log(isLoaded)
  })

  }, [])
```

Comment: Possibly a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57162865/react-onload-event-on-image-tag-is-not-getting-called-when-using-conditional-ren

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how react works. You are trying to use `load` event within the component when everything else is already loaded within from `<div id="root"></div>`.

React is Single Page App. And for the whole document `load` happens once only :)

However for individual elements we can set `onload` and fire that event in `componentDidMount()` or in `useEffect()` Hook

**UPDATE:** For image load check you do something like. You can do this or even use `useRef()`

```
  useEffect(() => {
 
   const imageTest = document.querySelector('img');
       imageTest.onload = ()=>{
       // Image is loaded and your further steps :)
       const isLoaded = imageTest.complete && imageTest.naturalHeight !== 0
       console.log(isLoaded);
      }

  }, []);
```

There is also one more easy way to do this:

Using `onLoad` synthetic event right on the image element itself. Which I think should also work fine:

```js
const ImageLoadDemo ()=> {

  const handleImageLoaded =()=> {
    console.log("Image was successfully loaded");
  }

  const handleImageErrored =()=> {
    console.log("Image was not loaded successfully");
  }


    return (
      <div>
        <img
          src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
          onLoad={handleImageLoaded}
          onError={handleImageErrored}
        />
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: do you know how to listen image when it is fully loaded in react component ?

Comment: Hi @arga Have updated my answer please have a look :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but actually the code is not work as well. After digging any information to listen image is fully loaded in component, I have found the answer. Let me answer this question by my self

Comment: Have also provided another way to achieve the same... Check my update once :)

Comment: Yeah you are right and so kind, thanks for that correct answer (using onLoad) my brother. May Allah bless you

Comment: Synthetic event onLoad is a very neat solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way to listen image is successfully loaded in react component is just put onLoad on your `<img>` tag, for example :

```
const MyCompoent = () => {
return <img src="yourImageLink.png" onLoad={()=>{console.log('The Image is successfully loaded')} } />
}
```

instead console a message you can pass a function as well

Comment: I have already updated it dear friend () :)